# UI Library Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, controls

I'm recently searching for custom UI Controls library. Is there any library consisting of different custom designed UI Controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) good Objective-C library for iPhone developers from the Facebook team.

Additional info at the [Three20 site](http://three20.info/).

Answer (score 0):

As jamapag capably pointed out, there are 3rd party libraries out there.

If you want a custom look or appearance, you can also design your own - many standard UIKit elements are customizable.

I'm not entirely sure what benefit using 3rd party libraries to replace standard UIKit elements such as navigation and title bar buttons would be. By using Apple-provided SDK elements, you future-proof your application's by ensuring you'll always be getting the latest and greatest enhancements from Apple and you won't break compatibility.